# Laravel Vue Variable

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am having trouble understanding how to combine Vue variables with Blade templates in Laravel.

This works:

```html
<ul id="media" v-if="files !== null">
    <li v-for="item in files">
        @{{ item.file }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

This does not work:

```html
<ul id="media" v-if="files !== null">
    <li v-for="item in files">
        <img src="{{ url('/storage') }}@{{ item.file }}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I combine Blade templates with Vue?

Comment: Are these single-file Vue components, or how are you using them on the page? I need a little more context (more code) from the views, and possibly the javascript (the part where you do `new Vue()`)

Comment: I use it in a normal blade template, not as component. The variable in vue is set correct and all is working. The problem is, that the variable @{{ item.file }} is not translated anymore if I use it in the img html part.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution myself - it has to be used this way:

```
<img :src="'storage/' + item.file">
```

Answer (score 0):

You must v-bind vue data objects to html attributes.